# Spring (Websockets / REST / Security), JWT and Sockjs (Stomp) integration

Tags: spring, websocket, jwt, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm developing a project and trying to integrate:

- Spring Security
- Spring Websockets
- Spring REST
- Sockjs & Stomp (Angular2)

I tried through google/spring docs/jwt examples and I cannot find anywhere a nicely explained and working (most importantly) example. Does anyone have example where mentioned are integrated (it does not have to be angular2, Sockjs & Stomp & Spring will do).
Important part here is security that can work for both websockets & REST with JWT. Please help it's just driving my crazy.

Comment: Short answer - it is possible. What exactly your problem? Your question is too broad and probably will be closed soon.

Comment: Hi user1516875, this is exactly the problem I'm facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102947/spring-security-block-websocket-sockjs . I did not want to mix both together. Thanks a lot for your interest, this problems doesn't let me sleep at night.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is define custom **bearerTokenResolver** method in `SecurityConfig`  and put access token into cookies or parameter.

```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/info", "/api/foos/**")
                    .hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/foos")
                    .hasAuthority("SCOPE_write")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().and().bearerTokenResolver(this::tokenExtractor);
}
...
}

public String tokenExtractor(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (header != null)
        return header.replace("Bearer ", "");
    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "access_token");
    if (cookie != null)
        return cookie.getValue();
    return null;
}
```